# When will "runlevel" event be emitted?

Tags: upstart, runlevel

```
start on runlevel [2345]
```

referring [this](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#start-on):

The syntax of start on stanza is:

> ```
> start on EVENT [[KEY=]VALUE]... [and|or...]
> ```

It means, `runlevel` is en event, `[2345]` is that event's  environment variables' value.

My question is

- when will `runlevel` event be emitted?
- Where can I dig more information about `runlevel` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#startup-process) (steps 9-11):

> Since the `start on` condition for the `rc-sysinit` job is:
>
> ```
> start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=lo
> ```
>
> Upstart will then start the `rc-sysinit` job.
>
> The `rc-sysinit` job calls the `telinit`command, passing it the runlevel to move to:
>
> ```
> telinit 2
> ```
>
> The `telinit` command emits the `runlevel(7)`event as:
>
> ```
> runlevel RUNLEVEL=2 PREVLEVEL=N
> ```

So, the `runlevel` is emitted once the filesystems are mounted and the loopback device is up.

To dig up more information, read the Upstart cookbook (completely, not bits and pieces).